# AWS RDS slow task status update during native restore

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, log-shipping

I was trying using AWS RDS MSSQL as my offsite instance (DR purpose) from on premise instance which already have primary and secondary DB. The DB size is quite large which make I decided to perform transaction log ship method.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-native-sql-server-log-shipping-and-powershell-scripts-to-synchronize-data-to-amazon-rds-for-sql-server/

My setup similar to the link as above in restoration part which will running to grab transaction log file from S3 which uploaded from on premise and run powershell to perform log ship restore to rds.
But the issue is when I run following queries in RDS:

> EXEC msdb.dbo.rds_task_status;

I can observe average 2-3 minutes duration in each task. I have average 96 transaction logs (15 minutes log backup) to restore in a day, which these delay causing my log ship restoration took very long period. Any way I can configure to improve this or is there better way to check for the status? [image: Sample image]

Side Info: From the task info, it's seems restore log are extremely fast actually, but there is delay in S3 processing part.
[image]